# ASIHTTPRequest Get Request - Delegate Not Getting Called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, xcode4.2, asihttprequest

My request is

```
        NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    if(request_) {
        [request_ setDelegate:nil];
        [request_ release];
    }
    request_ = [[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl] retain];
    [request_ setDelegate:self];
    [request_ setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request_ setTimeOutSeconds:HTTP_TIME_OUT];
    [request_ startAsynchronous];
```

The call is going since the network access indicator on the top bar is rotating and disappearing after a few seconds. But either of the delegate methods

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

or

`- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request`

is not being called. What could have went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sometimes, due to some issue, server is returning a "500 Internal Server Error". But even in that case, shouldn't the delegate

`- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request`

be called?

Comment: Use the NSLog to print some values. Also have you implemented the methods in the class? As you are assigning the delegate to self, there should be a definition of the methods in the same class.

Comment: I have implemented them. That is how I was able to know those were not being called.. :) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the blocks to check that out.

here is the example of the same:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setCompletionBlock:^{
      // Use when fetching text data
      NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

      // Use when fetching binary data
      NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
   }];
   [request setFailedBlock:^{
      NSError *error = [request error];
   }];
   [request startAsynchronous];
```

I hope this might help.

Comment: Thanks dude. That one indirectly helped me to find out what was the issue. I was making the delegate nil at some other part of my code.

Comment: I had the same problem, but switching to blocks instead of implementing the ASIHTTPRequestDelegate and using the delegate methods, helped me. I still don't know why and I have a old release of the app where the EXACT same code works with the delegates..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your class is conforming to the `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate` protocol.

```
@interface YourClass : ... <ASIHTTPRequestDelegate>
```

Comment: Yes it is..still not calling :(